# How to get Eclipse CDT to use the correct Linux headers and stop throwing semantic errors?

Tags: c, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, eclipse-cdt

There are many different answers circling around this topic, but I think my problem might be a bit more specific, as none work.

I am using Eclipse (v3.8.1) to build a C application for an embedded target. I use LTIB to build the target image, and I have been able to confirm that the GCC toolchain provided by LTIB (for a Freescale i.MX processor) is sound - I can successfully build and deploy a "Hello World" application to the target.

Now I'm trying to include some Linux headers *for the target* in Eclipse. So, I add a VAR to `${LTIB_LOC} = /home/user/ltib` in Eclipse and add the include file directories *everywhere seemingly imaginable (with help from other answers)*.

```
${LTIB_LOC}/rpm/BUILD/linux-2.6.31/include
```

And in the source code, I add the headers I need:

```
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/imx_types.h>
```

Now, the problem is two-fold. Firstly, the common header `types.h` is being picked-up from the built-in host directories (`/usr/include/linux`), whereas I want to use the ones in the LTIB directories. Secondly, the custom i.MX header `imx_types.h` cannot be found by the Eclipse discovery scanners, so I have persistent semantic warnings/errors, even though the compiler can find the headers and the project builds.

How can I get rid of the built-in host directories so that I always use the target Linux headers, and how do I get rid of the incredibly annoying semantic errors?

Comment: Mean you that ctrl+click drives you to the local header instead of the SDK one?

Comment: @LPs Yes, that's right.

Comment: Did you change project properties `C/C++Build->Environment`?

Comment: No, no change in that specific place.

Comment: Try using "Replace native..." and set PATH variable

Comment: To your needs: sdk rootFS path where to find headers an libs.

Comment: No luck. I set `${PATH}` to `/home/user/ltib/rpm/BUILD/linux-2.6.31/include` and there's no change on both accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your built-in compiler settings provider to find the correct toolchain.

Go to `Project Properties | C/C++ General | Providers`. Select `[Your Toolchain] Built-in Compiler Settings`, and in the `Command to get compiler specs`, replace `${COMMAND}` with the path to your cross-compiler.

This should get CDT to stop picking up the built-in includes of the system's default toolchain, and start picking up the built-in includes of your cross-compiler toolchain.

(Yes, replacing `${COMMAND}` with an explicit path is hacky. The *proper* way to do this, at least in the minds of the developers who designed this system, is to have the cross-compiler's developers distribute an Eclipse plugin that defines its *own* `[Cross Compiler Name] Built-in Compiler Settings` provider, which knows where the compiler executable is (i.e. for which `${COMMAND}` is the right thing to begin with), and use that instead of the default built-in settings provider. I assume you do not have such an Eclipse plugin handy.)

Comment: Thanks for this - I consigned the problem to the scrap heap quite a while ago but I'll be sure to use the information in the future.